# Syntax error near unexpected token `(' with mv !(build)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I am trying to run the following shell command with Jenkins build process

```
mv !(build) build
```

Now the build fails saying

```
$ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/jenkins2925091423898519645.sh
/tmp/jenkins2925091423898519645.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

But the strange thing is, when running this command directly on a Jenkin slave, it works fine.

As you can see, Jenkins run the shell commands with **`/bin/bash -xe`** as well.

Any help would be appreciated because i am struggling with this for hours

Comment: If it's possible to make a title specific enough that someone can tell if they're having the same problem without having to click through to the text, please *do that* -- it makes your question more useful to others. I've tried to edit towards that end here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!(build)` is an extended pattern, enabled by `shopt -s extglob`. It's not clear how it's being enabled in your Jenkins slave, but adding that command to your script should solve your problem.